# Deserialize repeating XML elements in Simple 2.5.3 (Java)

Tags: java, xml, xml-deserialization

Let's say the following XML is given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResC>
    <Err text="Error text 1"/>
    <ConRes>
        <Err text="Error text 2"/>
        <ConList>
            <Err text="Error text 3"/>
            <Con>
                <Err text="Error text 4"/>
            </Con>
        </ConList>
    </ConRes>
</ResC>
```

As you can see the `<Err>` element may appear on every level of the XML.

Using [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net) I would like to deserialize this XML. So, I have created the following class:

```
@Element(required=false)
public class Err {
    @Attribute
    private String text;

    public void setText(String text) { this.text = text; }

    public String getText() { return text; }
}
```

However, how do I have to annotate the classes for `<ResC>`, `<ConRes>`, `<ConList>` and `<Con>`? Do I really have to declare an attribute of type `<Err>` in every single class in which it may appear? This seems like a lot of overhead. If so, then I would have to check every single object if it contains an error.

Is there any better and easier way? :-)

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that Simple XML should be able to follow any structure that you can logically generate using classes. So you could just create a BaseClass that uses an error interface and applies the Decorator pattern so that it passes all of that through to a concrete error class without any of the implementing objects needing to know what they have been given.

That probably made no sense. How about I just show you...okay...I just went away and implemented exactly what I was thinking and here are the results ([full code link](http://www.mediafire.com/?pm9333eps9evqtm)):

**The Main File:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import java.io.File;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Serializer serial = new Persister();
        ResC resc = serial.read(ResC.class, new File("data/testdata.xml"));

        System.out.println(" == Printing out all of the error text. == ");
        System.out.println(resc.getErrorText());
        System.out.println(resc.conRes.getErrorText());
        System.out.println(resc.conRes.conList.getErrorText());
        for (Con con : resc.conRes.conList.cons) {
            System.out.println(con.getErrorText());
        }
        System.out.println(" == Finished printing out all of the error text. == ");
    }
}
```

It just runs simple and displays the results.

**The BaseObject.java class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class BaseObject implements Error {
    @Element(name = "Err", required = false, type = ConcreteError.class)
    private Error err;

    @Override
    public String getErrorText() {
        return err.getErrorText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorText(String errorText) {
        err.setErrorText(errorText);
    }
}
```

This is the class that everything should extend if it wants 'Err'.

**The Error interface:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

public interface Error {
    void setErrorText(String errorText);

    String getErrorText();
}
```

**The ConcreteError class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;

public class ConcreteError implements Error {
    @Attribute
    private String text;

    @Override
    public String getErrorText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorText(String errorText) {
        this.text = errorText;
    }

}
```

The actual implementing classes are after this point. You will see that they are rather trivial because the real work is being handled in the classes above.

**The Con class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

public class Con extends BaseObject {

}
```

**The ConList class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

public class ConList extends BaseObject {
    @ElementList(entry = "Con", inline = true)
    public ArrayList<Con> cons;
}
```

**The ConRes class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class ConRes extends BaseObject {
    @Element(name = "ConList")
    public ConList conList;
}
```

**The ResC class:**

```
package com.massaiolir.simple.iface;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class ResC extends BaseObject {
    @Element(name = "ConRes")
    public ConRes conRes;
}
```

And that is all that there is to it. Pretty simple right. I was able to bang that all out in ten minutes. It actually took me longer to write this response than it took me to write the code that I am giving you. If you do not understand anything about the code that I have just written then please let me know. I hope this helps you to understand how you might go about doing something like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code example. That's exactly what I've been looking for :-)

Comment: @Robert Strauch: No problems, hopefully it helps other people too.