# Get origin class of object instance

Tags: java, class, extends

My Java application needs to serialize/deserialize an XML structure received via HTTP. This XML message may contain an Error element on almost any level of the XML. That's why all classes extend `ApiError`. Please see the following question as well: [Deserialize repeating XML elements in Simple 2.5.3 (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6197196/478406)

I have created the following class:

```
public class ApiError {
  private String code;
  private String level;
  private String text;

  public get/set...() {}

}
```

Almost every other class in my application extends the `ApiError` class as those classes may raise an error.

I'd like to have a method like `getErrorOrigin()` which returns the name of the class which first created an instance of `ApiError`?

Is there an easy way in Java how to do this?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: If you are throwing exceptions and not swallowing the stack trace it will tell you the originator.

Comment: You should probably have your `ApiError` extend `java.lang.Exception`, than you would have access to the stack trace, which I guess would solve your problem.  Otherwise (ugly) you could have an argument in the constructor of `ApiError` which is a `Class` defined by the object where your error is created (e.g. `new ApiError(this.getClass())`.  You can then output this class name when you want it. [Edit: it's the solution from Ted Hopp below.]

Comment: Not an answer to your current question, but you might want to reconsider you design: I doubt that every class has an extends relationship with an `ApiError` class: it looks more like `ApiError` is an interface which all of your classes implement. If you don't want that, you might add an `ApiError` object to your classes, rather then extend it.

Comment: Wow, it's like Exceptions, but reinvented.

Comment: Some more background information: all classes are used for serializing/deserializing an XML structure received via HTTP. This XML message may contain an `Error` element on almost any level of the XML. That's why I'm extending all classes from `ApiError`. Please see the following question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6197196/478406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, by getting the stack trace of the current thread in the `ApiError` constructor:

```
public ApiError() {
    StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    this.errorOrigin = trace[2].getClassName();
}
```

You can see why this works by putting

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

in the `ApiError` constructor. If you create a new instance of `ApiError`, you'll see a stack trace that looks like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
        at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1249)
        at ApiError.<init>(Test.java:39)
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` will give you an array of `StackTraceElement` objects:

- The first element of that array will be for the `getStackTrace()` method itself, which is executing when the trace is generated.
- The 2nd element will be the `ApiError` constructor, which called `getStackTrace()`.
- The 3rd element - the one you want (hence the index `2`) - is for the method that called the `ApiError` constructor. By calling `getClassName()` on that element, you get the name of the class containing the method that invoked the `ApiError` constructor.

Having said all that, it seems you're trying to reimplement exceptions. I would seriously consider throwing exceptions from your methods, rather than returning `ApiError` objects. This keeps the error handling separate from your 'business logic'. Also errors are (hopefully) an exceptional situation, so it makes sense to use exceptions for error handling, rather than having `ApiError` pollute your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

*all classes extend one ...* Very bad idea. Anyway, just a hint: see if `Thread.getStackTrace()` is useful for you ...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the name of the class containing the code that used the `new` operator, then declare a field in ApiError `Object originator`, add an argument of type Object to the ApiError constructor, and in the creating code pass `this`. Then you can use `originator.getClass().getName()`. You'll have to punt if you are creating one of these from a static block or static method.

Comment: Probably better to pass only the class name as argument since passing the actual object keeps it from being garbage collected.

Comment: Good point. Probably the best strategy is to pass the object to the c'tor but store only the class name in the ApiError object.